# Is there an avilable Fix for the Managed metadata navigation Bug in sharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, managed-metadata

I am facing this bug on my "Publishing Site ---> enterprise wiki Template" inside SharePoint server 2013. and when i tried to specify the target page manually as mentioned in this link it did not work also.

http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/04/managed-metadata-navigation-and_21.html

So i would like to know if SharePoint has applied any fix this this Big?
BR